# Recursively search for a filename until file is found using python

Tags: python, loops, search

Using python, How can I loop through every line in Test.txt file and search for Android.mk file, if not found, go up a directory level and search again until a file is found?

/home/jenkins/workspace/art/build/apps/XYZ.cpp

In above path Android.mk is found under following location

```
/home/jenkins/workspace/art/build/apps/Android.mk
/home/jenkins/workspace/art/build/Android.mk
```

/home/jenkins/workspace/frameworks/base/rs/ABC.java

In above path Android.mk is found under following location

```
/home/jenkins/workspace/frameworks/Android.mk
```

**Test.txt**

/home/jenkins/workspace/art/build/apps/XYZ.cpp
/home/jenkins/workspace/frameworks/base/rs/ABC.java

**DesireOutput.txt**

```
/home/jenkins/workspace/art/build/apps/Android.mk
/home/jenkins/workspace/frameworks/Android.mk
```

MyTry

```
with open('/data/jenkins/workspace/Experiments/Test.txt','r') as f:
    for apps in f.readlines():
        print(apps.strip())
        dirs = os.listdir( apps.strip() )
        for file in dirs:
            #print file
            if file == 'Android.mk':
                print "Android.mk found"
            else:
                os.chdir(apps.strip())
                apps.strip()
                print "Android.mk not found"
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Are you aware of `os.walk`?

Comment: @wjandrea I think OP is probably looking for `os.listdir()` here though, since it seems he wants to search specific folders

Comment: @Reedinationer Oh right, `os.walk` descends, but OP wants to **a**scend.

Comment: @wjandrea there is a `topdown=False` option for `os.walk()` too though. Maybe that is what OP wants. Or maybe they would `os.listdir('/home/jenkins/workspace/art/build/apps')` then `os.listdir('/home/jenkins/workspace/art/build')` (automated of course). It's just too hard to tell without their code sample attempt what would be best

Comment: Hi  Wjandrea , @Reedinationer - I have sample code but it is in bash.. were i have a while loop and it is looking for file name "Android.mk" if not found it will "cd .." and then look again.. I was wondering if there is any better way to do it using python...

Comment: @Mihir I would point you to research the [`os` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html). Specifically the mentioned functions of `os.listdir()` which would be the more direct translation of your bash script when paired with `os.chdir('../')`. Or you may find `os.walk` to suit your needs better. Perhaps you would even like to use them together! When you have a code sample you can edit your post and drop a comment with @Reedinationer and I can take a look.

Comment: @Reedinationer - i have added my code sample but it is incorrect.

Comment: @Mihir How is it incorrect? Maybe include the printed output and explain why it's insufficient. I obviously don't have the files myself so it is hard to tell just from reading it without at least an idea of what is wrong

Comment: dirs = os.listdir( apps.strip() )  - is constant a the moment.. how can i do up a level and then do through that if loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script isn't going up a level using `os.chdir('../')`. Here is a script that implements that inside a while loop. You were calling `os.chdir(apps.strip())` every loop instead of the `os.chdir('../')` to move up a level.

```
with open('/data/jenkins/workspace/Experiments/Test.txt','r') as f:
    for apps in f.readlines():
        os.chdir(apps.strip()) # move into the folder here
        print("Starting search in {}".format(apps.strip()))
        found = False
        while not found:
            dirs = os.listdir(os.getcwd()) # print files in current directory (no argument needed)
            for file in dirs:
                if file == 'Android.mk':
                    print("Android.mk found")
                    found = True
                    break # end our for loop to save computations
            if not found:
                os.chdir("../") # move up a level for the next iteration of while loop 
                print("Android.mk not found...going up a level")
```

Also, `dirs = os.listdir()` should have no argument, so it is getting it for the current folder (the one we changed into). Otherwise, regardless of where you are in the file system it will return the same result.

Comment: thank you very much this was very helpful.. but i'm getting following error "TypeError: listdir() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)"

Comment: @Mihir I guess I remembered incorrectly and you need to supply `os.getcwd()`

Comment: it worked when i supplied os.listdir('.').. Again thank you very much